# Find insertions specific to each file in git

Tags: git

```
git diff --shortstat <cmmit1> <commit2>
```

gives me results :

```
File1                             |   2 +-
File2                              |  12 ++++++++++++
2 files changed, 13 insertions(+), 1 deletions(-)
```

where as I am looking for results which gives me results something like:

```
File1 | 1 insertions  1 deletion
File2 | 12 insertions 0 deletion
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try (looking at [`git diff` man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff)):

```
git diff --numstat
```

> Similar to `--stat`, but shows number of added and deleted lines in decimal notation and pathname without abbreviation, to make it more machine friendly.
>   For binary files, outputs two `-` instead of saying `0 0`.

Which outputs the lines added / removed for each files.

```
25      1       file1
28      0       file2
```

It isn't *exactly* the output you are looking for, but it is close.

Comment: Thanks, this output is enough for me to carry on.